# Test whether an unsorted list of integers with length n represents the set {1,...,n}

Tags: java, algorithm

Right now I have the following solution, which I believe to be reasonably clear.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class ConsecutiveNumbers {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> good = Arrays.asList(2, 1);
    System.out.println(is1ToN(good)); // true

    List<Integer> bad1 = Arrays.asList(3, 1);
    System.out.println(is1ToN(bad1)); // false

    List<Integer> bad2 = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2);
    System.out.println(is1ToN(bad2)); // false
  }

  public static boolean is1ToN(List<Integer> numbers) {
    SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(numbers);
    return set.isEmpty() || (set.size() == numbers.size() && set.first() == 1
        && set.last() == set.size());
  }
}
```

Is there a better (more efficient or clearer) solution, though?

Comment: Construction of the `TreeSet` takes `O(n log n)` time. If you maintain a boolean array `exists` and set the elements to true that are in the list and check if every element is set in a second pass, you get `O(n)`. But which one is actually more efficient must be assessed for the concrete scenario.

Comment: a sorted set takes o(n*log(n)) to create, since it has to sort the things. a shorter solution would be to create a simple set (o(n) to create), verify that it is of the right size, then verify that it contains all the elements. since `contains` is constant time in a set, that would take o(n) overall

Comment: Outlining your algorithm - i.e. what were you trying to do and how - would make your question way more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a boolean array, p, of size N. Iterate through your list, considering the value of each element of the list in turn, v. if v is outside the range 1...n, return false. If p[v-1] is true, you have a duplicate value, so the answer is false. Otherwise, set p[v-1] to true. If you reach the end of your list, return true.

It might or might not be worthwhile using a BitSet instead of an array. That will save some memory, although the extra memory required is still O(N). But it will increase the CPU work. Whether the trade is worth it will depend on the use case.

Comment: Good idea.  However, instead of creating a boolean array, use a Bitset.

Answer (score 2):

Following on my comment, an implementation could be:

```
public static boolean is1ToN(List<Integer> numbers) {
  Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(numbers);
  if (set.size() != numbers.size()) {
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < numbers.size() + 1; i++) {
    if (!set.contains(i)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```